# How to fix Error while reading greeting packet?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to connect to server in NetBeans.
I write the code as below:

```
<?php
echo "wlecome";
echo "<br>";

$conn=mysqli_connect("mydomain.com:2082", "phpmyadmin_user", "password","database_name");
                     
echo $conn;
?>
```

Running of this code return this erreurs:

```
wlecome

Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojet\index.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=1092 in C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojet\index.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojet\index.php on line 10

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojet\index.php on line 10
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure your SQL server is running and is on port 2082? From the error it looks like the server is not reachable.

Comment: yes i do it !!!! server run succefuuly (y) !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MySQL can be configured to not accept external connections, for security reasons.  By saying the full domain name, you are using the public IP and therefore you are an external connection.  If MySQL is running on the same box as your webserver, just access it via this domain name:

```
localhost:2082
```

Answer (score 5):

Try using only `localhost` without the port, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use brew services restart mysql@5.7
if you are using mysql 5.7 version.

Comment: What makes you think Homebrew is involved or available?

Comment: I am using mac i got same issue it's worked for me, If anyone using hmbrew then it's helpfull for them.