# unable to connect to a remote mysql db with pdo

Tags: php, pdo

i'm new to stackoverflow and i have a question i already try on loof on the forum but i didn't find answers,
i am trying to connect to a remote MySQL db using pdo, but i get the following message : 
[error pdo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsUOC.png)

here is my pdo connection, i don't know why it doesn't work because when i connect locally it works
`$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=185.31.xx.xx;port=xxxxx;dbname=monitoring', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');`
if someone can help me i would really appreciate it.
thanks!

Comment: Post the error message *here*, not as image somewhere else.

Comment: Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=21020

Comment: [Error while reading greeting packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18803440/error-while-reading-greeting-packet)

Comment: Are you sure that your external public IP 185.31.xx.xx accepts incoming requests from the world ?
Maybe it's not the case, if your script and your mysql server runs the same machine, juste use localhost (preferred 127.0.0.1).

Comment: i wll check it! thanks for your answer!

Comment: i have open port 3306 with this command:sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT, but it still doesn't work, i have also restart mysql

Comment: i am also able to connect to phpmyadmin without problem